# Number of rows in getItems

Tags: php, sharepoint

I was trying to get all the items from a list using the phpSPO library: https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO

However in the $remoteList properties in the array of Data there are only 100 rows, and the list has more than 100 items. I saw that it's a common problem, however I don't know which solution I should consider for this library.
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74777/list-api-get-all-items-limited-to-100-rows

```php
$remoteList = $web->getLists()->getByTitle(xxx)
$listData = $remoteList->getItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a public property for the `CamlQuery` class called `ListItemCollectionPosition` defined in this file:

https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/b05be0eba6902dabd18784576bb6e1d55426fa99/src/SharePoint/CamlQuery.php

That expects a `ListItemCollectionPosition` object as a value: https://github.com/vgrem/phpSPO/blob/b05be0eba6902dabd18784576bb6e1d55426fa99/src/SharePoint/ListItemCollectionPosition.php

So I think your code will need to look something like:

```
$remoteList = $web->getLists()->getByTitle(xxx);

$listItemCollectionPosition = new new ListItemCollectionPosition(); // Either add a use statement for this or use the fully qualified class name here
// ... (set the values according to the items/page you require)
$remoteList->ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItemCollectionPosition;

$listData = $remoteList->getItems();
```

In terms of how to use it exactly, have a read of the information here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee534956(v%3Doffice.14)#retrieving-items-using-list-item-collection-position

The example is in C# but it's not too hard to follow.

It looks as though you set the `ListItemCollectionPosition` on your query to get subsequent "pages". It also looks as though responses include a `ListItemCollectionPosition` property themselves that you can then use as a starting point for the next request.